# Getting my initials in logo style

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me out to achieve what's on the attached picture? It has to be with the same background circle and color.

[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mr}{M\MRkern R} \newcommand{\MRkern}{%   \mkern-6.5mu   \mathchoice{}{}{\mkern0.2mu}{\mkern0.5mu}% }

\begin{document}

$\mr$ $\scriptstyle\mr$ $\scriptscriptstyle\mr$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\MD{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[text=white,font=\Large\sffamily,draw=none,fill={rgb:red,54;green,58;blue,142}] (0,0) circle[radius=.8cm] node {MD};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
Test: \MD
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]